# parse csv using lua script

Tags: regex, csv, lua

I have a csv file that has data like this:

```
+12345678901,08:00:00,12:00:00,1111100,35703,test.domain.net
+12345678901,,,0000000,212,test.domain.net
```

I'm trying to write lua code that will loop through each line, and create an array of values like this:

```
local mylist = {}
for line in io.lines("data/dd.csv") do
        local id, start, finish, dow, int, domain = line:match("(+%d+),(%d*:*),(%d*:*),(%d*),(%d*),(%a*.*)")
        mylist[#mylist + 1] = { id = id, start = start, finish = finish, dow = dow, int = int, domain = domain}
        print(mylist[#mylist]['id'])
end
```

The problem is that when the code hits a line that has empty values for start and finish, the regex fails and all fields are nil.

I thought using the * meant 0 or more... 
I can't seem to find my error / typo.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `"(%+%d+),([0-9:]*),([0-9:]*),(%d*),(%d*),(.*)"`

Comment: that worked.  sheesh.  i would have never thought of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just need to group the digits and `:` inside  a `[...]`:

```
match("(%+%d+),([%d:]*),([%d:]*),(%d*),(%d*),(.*)")
        ^       ^^^^^^   ^^^^^^
```

Now, the `[%d:]*` matches zero or more digits or `:` symbols. Your pattern did not find the match because `%d*:*` matched 0+ digits followed with 0+ `:` symbols, and you had more than 1 such sequence.

Also, you need to escape the first `+` to make sure it matches a literal `+`.

See [online Lua demo](http://ideone.com/oc1G9N)

Answer (score 2):

This pattern works for me:

```
"(.-),(.-),(.-),(.-),(.-),(.-)$"
```